# Why with dot operator value is not changed in c++?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, pass-by-reference

I am from Javascript background and was experimenting with c++ where i wanted to mutate a struct member in an array in the caller function as below.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

typedef struct Node{
    int value;
    Node(int val){
        this->value = val;
    }
};
void changeValueByDot(Node* p, int idx){
    Node n = *(p + idx);
    n.value = 54;

}
void changeValueByArrow(Node* p, int idx){
    Node* n = (p + idx);
    n->value = 32;
};

int main(){
    vector<Node> v = {
        Node(1),
        Node(2)
    };
    
    
    changeValueByDot(v.data(), 1);
    cout<<"After changing by dot:"<<v[1].value<<endl;
    changeValueByArrow(v.data(), 1);
    cout<<"After changing by arrow:"<<v[1].value<<endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Now my confusion is why dot operator is unable to do permanent change while arrow operator could.
My expectation with dot was to first reach the place obtain node and change its value. I am not sure if the node at that location is getting copied and changes are done in copied node.

I tried with both vector and fixed size array only to get same result.

Please help me in understanding this.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On this line:

```
Node n = *(p + idx);
```

the variable `n` is a *copy* of the node on the right hand side. Modifying `n.value` won't change the node referred to on the right hand side.

If you want `n` to refer to the dereferenced node, then use a reference:

```
Node & n = *(p + idx);
  // ^
```

Now changes to `n` will be reflected in changes to `*(p + idx)`

---

Note that this is not a problem when you do:

```
Node* n = (p + idx);
```

because while `n` is still a *copy*, it's a copy of a *pointer*, and modifying `n->value` will actually change the `value` member of the same object pointed at by `p + idx`.

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't have variables of object type.  Java has variables which refer to objects.

This is because Java gc requires objects to exist on the heap, and pretty much never where you put them.  In C++ terms, Java object variables are fancy smart pointers.

```
void changeValueByDot(Node* p, int idx){
  Node n = *(p + idx);
  n.value = 54;
}
```

this code creates a local (on stack) object if type `Node` called `n`.

The rough Java "pseudocode" equivalent is either:

```
void changeValueByDot(Node p, int idx){
  Node n = (p + idx).clone();
  n.value = 54;
}
```

or

```
void changeValueByDot(int reference p, int idx){
  int n = p;
  n = 54;
}
```

in the first case we make the implicit dupkication of the object in C++ explicit.  In the second, we use a type that Java doesn't implicitly turn into a reference.

In both cases, obviously only the local data is modified.  So the same happens with the C++ version.

Java's lack of object instance variables means that it treats primitives and objects asymmetrically.  C++ objects, on the other hand, act like primitives.  You can write a replacement `int` in C++ and have its semantics be identical to the base int, but under the hood it is a variable sized arbitrary precision bigint.